# Connecting Wget and Sed Commands in One Script?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I use 3 commands (wget/sed/and a tr/sort) that all work in command line to produce a most-common words list. I use commands sequentially, saving output from sed to use in the tr/sort command. Now I need to graduate to writing a script that combines these 3 commands. So, 1) wget downloads a file, that I put into 2) `sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' wget-file.txt`, and that output > goes to 3)

```
cat sed-output.txt | tr -cs A-Za-z\'  '\n' | tr A-Z  a-z | sort | uniq -c | 
sort -k1,1nr -k2 | sed ${1:-100}q > words-list.txt
```

I'm aware of the problem/debate about using regex to remove HTML tags, but these 3 commands are working for me for the moment. So thanks in helping pull this together.

Comment: It seems as if you already know how to pipe output from one command to another. It's not clear what you're asking that you're not already doing. You can `wget -O- http://... | sed ... | tr ...`

Comment: Thanks larsks, piping output does it (and wrapping new lines \ for ease).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command should do the job:

```
wget -O- http://down.load/file | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' | \
tr -cs A-Za-z\'  '\n' | tr A-Z  a-z | sort | uniq -c | \
sort -k1,1nr -k2 | sed ${1:-100}q > words-list.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk.

```
wget -O- http://down.load/file| awk '{ gsub(/<[^>]*>/,"")                # remove the content in label <>
       $0=tolower($0)                    # convert all to lowercase
       gsub(/[^a-z]]*/," ")              # remove all non-letter chars and replaced by space
       for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++       # save each word in array a, and sum it.
     }END{for (i in a) print a[i],i|"sort -nr|head -100"}'   # print the result, sort it, and get the top 100 records only
```

Comment: Thanks for the awk example. Would you please show how to include the wget page/file download? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sure, updated. Pipe wget output to awk command: `wget command |awk `

Comment: I'm trying your script, which gives "Cannot write to `-' (No error)." and no output file is created. I've tried with > before output file, which creates empty file. I've also tried \ end of lines, which throws "\ is not last character" error. Sed script works, but I'd like learn from your awk solution as well. So would you please confirm/check out why this isn't working? Also, learning awk, ^ symbol matches beginning of string, but seems in gsub(/[^a-z]]*/," ") that ^ is excepting anything that's not a letter? And why the comma before open quotes? Not finding , in man awk. Thanks.

Comment: I fix one issue (remove index.hmtl from awk command, which needn't). Now it should be fine.

Comment: says "written to stdout" but not showing words in terminal, and not writing to a file either.

Comment: I test again, and seems fine in my env (CYGWIN), could you please show me the awk version? `awk --version |head -1`. If you run awk in Solaris, please use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`.

Comment: BMW, it's working great in both stdout and outputting > file back at home on Linux, GNU Awk 4.0.1. Was not outputting on CYGWIN at friend's house. Will check out awk version later there...but THANKS! Using awk is awesome and gives me more of a programming method to learn from as well. Really appreciate your help.